# How do I specify the two extensions that uses native messaging to a the same host in the allowed_origins field?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json, chrome-native-messaging

I created two extensions that uses native messaging to a the same host.

The native application manifest.json:

{
"name": "com.google.chrome.example.echo",
"description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",
"path": "./resources/example.exe",
"type": "stdio",
"**allowed_origins**": [
"chrome-extensions://fegpbklgdffjmfjmhnpmgepbddbchk/"
]
}

How do I specify the two extensions in the allow_origins field?

Thanks

Comment: Use a comma: `,`

Comment: Would the following be correct:

{ "name": "com.google.chrome.example.echo", "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host", "path": "./resources/example.exe", "type": "stdio", 
"allowed_origins": [ "chrome-extensions://fegpbklgdffjmfjmhnpmgepbddbchk/","chrome-extensions://fegpbklgdffjmfjmhnpmgepbddbfff/" ] }

Comment: Could you confirm that this is correct? "allowed_origins": [ "chrome-extensions://fegpbklgdffjmfjmhnpmgepbddbchk/","chrome-extensions://fegpbklgdffjmfjmhnpmgepbddbfff/" ] }